# FlatList re-render with Redux

Tags: ios, react-native, redux

I'm using PureComponent to render items of my FlatList and when I use FlatList and pass a local state to it in data, the rendering works very well, I don't have wasteful re-rendering.
However, when I use FlatList with an array from my redux store in data, if I scroll down, each time that onReachEnd is called, re-render work well. But when I don't have anymore data to load and I scroll up, all my items re-render one per one.

Like my whole list is lost.

I'm using exactly the same list with local state in data, and it works perfectly! 
The issue only appear when I try to make FlatList and Redux work together

```
<FlatList
   ref={(view) => this.list = view}
   data={this.props.requestsList}
   style={{flex: 1}}
   keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.emitter.id)}
   renderItem={this._renderRequestsItems}
   onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
   onEndReached={!this.props.lastPage ? this._endReached : null}
   ListFooterComponent={reloadIndicator}
   ListHeaderComponent={this._getHeaderComponent}
   ListEmptyComponent={this._getEmptyComponent}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `extraData` property on your FlatList component, in your case, extra data can come from props so it will look like

```
extraData={this.prop}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! 
I already did it! With this.props and this.state!
Is it possible that because of store which is immutable, when my componentShouldUpdate compare my previous props with my new props, it said "it's not from same object, so it's different, bam update" ?
I'll continue to testing and come back to you to say if it works!

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but I just realized something.
When I put a console.log() in my ItemList component's componentDidMount function, each time render is calling, didMount is calling too. As if I'm not updating the itemList but I remount it each time!
What am I do wrong ?

Comment: Try to change implementation inside `renderItem={this._renderRequestsItems}` to
`renderItem={(item)=><RequestItem item={item}/>}`

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I tried what you said but it didn't work!
It is possible that the re-render is caused because my list is too large? So for optimization memory, react unmount my items ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add a new key to flat list?

```
 <FlatList
   key={Math.floor(Math.random())} 
   ref={(view) => this.list = view}
   data={this.props.requestsList}
   style={{flex: 1}}
   keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.emitter.id)}
   renderItem={this._renderRequestsItems}
   onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
   onEndReached={!this.props.lastPage ? this._endReached : null}
   ListFooterComponent={reloadIndicator}
   ListHeaderComponent={this._getHeaderComponent}
   ListEmptyComponent={this._getEmptyComponent}
/>
```

It is work for me.

Comment: the wrong answer, it doesn't helps